# Get the value inside 2D ArrayList in android?

Tags: java, android

I have a 2D array like ...

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<MParsingClass>> 2d_arraylist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<MParsingClass>>();
```

I want to get all the Value of the internal Object class like the value of position ...

```
2d_arraylist [0][1] and gradually so on.....
```

Any Help Please ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Have to make a 2 for loop like this ...

```
for(int i=o ; i< size of 2d array ;i++)
```

// here you have to make another ArrayList which will get the positon of the "i th"
//array of your 2D array..

```
ArrayList<MParsingClass> new_array_list = 2d_arraylist .get(position);

for(int j=o ; i<size of  new_array_list ;i++)

new_array_list.get(your get value)


{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That would work if you were dealing with nested *arrays*, but you are dealing with nested `ArrayList`s you have to use `ArrayList` class methods to access its data, namely the `get()` method.

You need to use:

```
2d_arraylist.get(0).get(1);
```

`get(0)` gets the first row from your array of arrays (an ArrayList)

`get(1)` gets the second column from the row you have selected (an MParsingClass)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for(i=0; i<2d_arraylist.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<MParsingClass> temp = 2d_arraylist.get(i);
    for(j=0; j<temp.size(); j++) {
        MParsingClass obj = temp.get(j);
        //To-Do .....
    }
}
```